# How to open links in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I want to create a single `iframe` in which I want to load both links below:

```
<a href="http://www.deccanchronicle.com" target="loadWebPages">News</a><br>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5y8tkqs77Q" target="loadWebPages">Android Video</a><br>
<iframe id="loadWebPages" src="http://www.google.com" style="width:900px; height:480px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace ?

Comment: I don't understand your question... Replace what?

Comment: I'm asking that there  any way replace old frame with new one when i click video button.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Your problem is that Google (and therefore YouTube) do not allow you to embed their pages in an iframe. Press F12 if you're using Chrome. In your console log you'll see `Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5y8tkqs77Q' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqDrn/show/). The *News* link works.

Comment: Hey @DannyBeckett you're right. Post that as an answer plus how he get youtube's embeed videos and it will be accepted.